# Zabbix - The buffer pool utilization is too low

Tags: mysql, buffer, innodb, zabbix

I'm using Zabbix as my Linux monitoring solution.
It shows `MySQL - The buffer pool utilization is less than 50% in the last 5 minutes. This means that there is a lot of unused RAM allocated for the buffer pool, which you can easily reallocate at the moment` as a warning.

should I worry about this do?
How to overcome this issue?

Comment: only if it comes all the time, but it s not unususal when out od teh office hours the load is quote reduces. If it comes during peak times, you can reduce the buffer size.

Comment: Comment to the comment of nbk: It's also a good idea to change the Zabbix trigger so that trigger will be become TRUE after a much longer time (than 5 minutes)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have configured your MySQL with more RAM than needed, check your configuration (`my.cnf`, `my.cnf.d` and so on) for the `innodb_buffer_pool_size` and lower it.

How much lower? It depends on the effective usage, you can see it on your Zabbix graphs.

Don't forget to restart the mysql service!

Answer (score 1):

If you are not swapping, and nothing else would benefit from using the RAM that this is wasting, then don't worry.  (There's an old saying: "If it ain't broke, don't fix it.")